# Multistep ODE Solvers

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Write both a fourth order Adams Bashforth and Adams Moulton procedure to solve

$$x'(t) = x(t)-y(t)-\exp(t);$$

$$y'(t) = x(t)+y(t)+2\exp(t)$$

with initial values $x(0) = -1, y(0) =- 1$ on the interval $0 \le t \le 4.$

Use the analytical solution to find the staring values.
The analytical solution is:

$$x(t) = \exp(t)\cos(t)-2\exp(t);$$

$$y(t) = \exp(t)\sin(t)-\exp(t)$$

I need to plot the solution (by PYTHON, if possible?) and verify the convergence rate.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps if you share your thoughts and what you have tried so we can provide better guidance and not rehash things you already know. I suspect that is why you got downvoted. Adding those details is very helpful. Regards

Comment: Did you mean for this to just list the values for each fourth order method or to use these two methods in concert as a Predictor - Corrector for the solution? My guess would be the latter, but not sure you are there yet.

Answer (score 3):

**Adams-Bashfourth Four-Step Method**

The Adams-Bashfourth Four-Step Method is given by:

- $w_0 = a = 0, w_1 = \alpha_1, w_2 = \alpha_2, w_3 = \alpha_3$
- $\displaystyle w_{i+1} = w_i + \frac{h}{24}\left[55 f(t_i, w_i) - 59 f(t_{i-1}, w_{i-1}) + 37 f(t_{i-2}, w_{i-2}) - 9 f(t_{i-3},w_{i-3})\right]$

where $i = 3, 4, \ldots N-1$.

The local truncation error is $\displaystyle \tau_{i+1}(h) = \frac{251}{720}y^{(5)}\left(\mu_i\right)h^4, t_{i-3} \lt \mu_i \lt t_{i+1}$.

**Adams-Moulton Four-Step Method**

The Adams-Moulton Four-Step Method is given by:

- $w_0 = a = 0, w_1 = \alpha_1, w_2 = \alpha_2, w_3 = \alpha_3$
- $\displaystyle w_{i+1} = w_i + \frac{h}{720}\left[251 f(t_{i+1}, w_{i+1}) + 646 f(t_i, w_i) - 264 f(t_{i_1}, w_{i-1}) + 106 f(t_{i-2}, w_{i-2}) - 19 f(t_{i-3}, w_{i-3})\right]$

where $i = 3, 4, \ldots N-1$.

The local truncation error is $\displaystyle \tau_{i+1}(h) = -\frac{3}{160}y^{(6)}\left(\mu_i\right)h^5, t_{i-3} \lt \mu_i \lt t_{i+1}$.

These methods are typically used in concert as a Predictor (Adams- Bashfourth) - Corrector (Adams - Moulton) approach. We calculate the predictor step and immediately follow that calculation by a corrector step (in other words, we calculate an $x_{i,P}, y_{i,P}$ and follow that up with calculating $x_{i,C}, y_{i,C}$).

For our system, we have two equations, so just do two sets of calculations at each step.

To calculate the four starting values, we use the given analytic solution since these values are needed for each method.

- We will use $N = 10$ (change this if you were asked for a different value).
- $h = \dfrac{b-a}{N} = \dfrac{4-0}{10} = \dfrac{2}{5}$
- Using, $t = 0.0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2$, this yields:
- $x(t) = e^t \cos t - 2 e^t \rightarrow \{-1, -1.60959, -2.90053, -5.43716\}$
- $y(t) = e^t \sin t - e^t  \rightarrow \{-1, -0.910881, -0.629036, -0.225638\}$
- These are our values for $w_0 = a = 0, w_1, w_2, ~~ \text{and} ~~~ w_3$.

Now, lets use all of this and do a calculation for the next set of values using all of the methods, that is, for $i = 3, t = 1.6$, we have:

Adams-Bashfourth (Predictor Steps)

$\displaystyle x_4 = x_3 + \frac{0.4}{24} \left[ 55 f_3 - 59 f_2 + 37 f_1 - 9 f_0 \right] = -5.43716 +(0.4/24)(55 (-8.53164) -59(-4.49704) +37(-2.19053) -9(-1)) = -10.0365675$

$\displaystyle y_4 = y_3 + \frac{0.4}{24}\left[55 g_3 - 59 g_2 + 37 g_1 - 9 g_0\right] = -0.225638 +(0.4/24)\left[55 (0.977436) -59(0.921522) +37(0.463178) -9(0)\right] = 0.04980813333$

$f(x,y,t) = x - y -e^t \rightarrow f_4 = f(x_4, y_4, t_4) = -10.0365675 - 0.04980813333 -e^{1.6} = -15.0394080577251148$

$g(x,y,t) = x + y +2e^t \rightarrow g_4 = g(x_4, y_4, t_4) = -10.0365675 + 0.04980813333 +2e^{1.6} = -0.080694517879770392691427287$

Adams-Moulton (Corrector Steps)

$\displaystyle x_4 = x_3 + \frac{0.4}{720}\left[251 f_4 + 646 f_3 - 264 f_2 + 106 f_1 - 19 f_0\right] = -5.43716 +(0.4/720)\left[251 (-15.0394080577251148) + 646 (-8.53164) -264 (-4.49704) + 106 (-2.19053) -19 (-1)\right] = -10.05510915693833545266666666$

$\displaystyle y_4 = y_3 + \frac{0.4}{720}\left[251 g_4 + 646 g_3 - 264 g_2 + 106 g_1 - 19 f_0\right] = -0.225638 +(0.4/720)\left[251 (-0.080694517879770392691427287) + 646 (0.977436) -264 (0.921522) + 106 (0.463178) -19 (0)\right] = 0.006019995562320906352473194979444444444$

The previous two values for $x_i, y_i$ are the values we enter into the table as corrected to use for the next calculations.

Lets create a table of these values for you to fill out as follows (I will let you fill in the rest of the table so you can get your hands around what is going on).

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline i  & t_i & x_i & y_i & f_i & g_i  \\ \hline
00 & 0.0 &  -1 & -1  & -1  & 0    \\ \hline   
01 & 0.4 & -1.60959 & -0.910881&-2.19053 & 0.463178 \\ \hline
02 & 0.8 & -2.90053  & -0.629036   & -4.49704     & 0.921522 \\ \hline
03 & 1.2 & -5.43716  & -0.225638   & -8.53164     & 0.977436 \\ \hline
04 & 1.6 &  -10.0551091 & 0.00601999&-15.0394080 & -0.0806945 \\ \hline
05 & 2.0 & & & &  \\ \hline
06 & 2.4 & & & &  \\ \hline
07 & 2.8 & & & &  \\ \hline
08 & 3.2 & & & &  \\ \hline
09 & 3.6 & & & &  \\ \hline
10 & 4.0 & & & &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Note: if you didn't want to use the two methods in concert, you are still generating all of the same data and can add more columns to the table for the AB method, AM method, the error for each method, plus exact results for comparison purposes.

For the second parts of your question:

- Plot the values of tables for $x_i, y_i$ for calculated versus analytic using whatever you like (why Python, unless being used in class).

In other words, here is the analytic plot for (you can plot it as a parametric plot also) $x(t), y(t)$, over the range $0 \le t \le 4$:

[image]

- For the convergence rates, I provided the truncation error and you have the analytic solution, so can use those to perform that calculation and verification.

Comment: Before I saw the question, I couldn't guess who solved the problem. But when I encountered a proof which was getting long, I made sure I would see your name at last. It was right! That's you Amzoti. :-) +1

Comment: I had the same thought process as @Babak! ;-) +1

Comment: @BabakS.: Thank you my friend! I had never seen these used for a system of equations, so was curious how you would do it. An interesting problem. Regards and good to see you on!

Comment: Seems a rather slow night...but then, I was on the phone for an hour or so...so might have missed some *action*.

Comment: Yes...there may be some summer term activity, but will unlikely start this week.  Good luck on your presentation tomorrow (luck, I'm sure, isn't needed here)!